# How to ensure electronic components make good connection with breadboard

Tags: arduino-uno

I just began following the projects in the Arduino Projects Book included in the Arduino Starter Kit.

While using LEDs, as in the first few examples of the book, I am having a difficult time keeping them in contact with the breadboard. I can usually move the LED around until it turns on, but even a push of a button can make it lose contact with the board. I haven't used much more than switches, jumpers, LEDs and resistors, so I don't know if any of the other components behave the same. For the more complex projects, it seems like it would be hard to tell if you have it setup properly if you can't be sure the components are making a connection with the breadboard.

Is there a particular way to get all the components to sit nicely in the breadboard, or to modify them to do so?

Comment: Bend the pins as little as possible.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm trying not to. Any other tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you may not be pushing the leads into the board,I find long nose pliers handy for components with thicker leads.

Comment: I feel silly! You're right, I wasn't actually pushing the leads into the board, just letting them rest in the slots. Working great now. Thanks